# Wordpress Website now showing 404 Error? Can't fix

Tags: wordpress, godaddy, http-status-code-404

My website: www.kmskinboutique.com

It is now showing a 404 Error warning on 1/2 the page (on the homepage & tabs).  Nothing is missing - the warning just pushed my website down.  I have searched & can't figure out how to repair.  Any help out there??  I recently updated all of my Plug-Ins so I'm not sure which one may have caused this (if they did at all!)

Thanks in Advance!
~K

Answer (score 1):

Your site was compromised, but the malware site that it linked to has been taken down. You will need to clean up and reinstall WordPress, and most likely the entire server.

Comment: Michael, Does that mean I will need to re-do my entire site? :/  Delete everything and re-add it all?  Thanks!